# Converting Binary File into Audio File

Tags: java, android

How can I convert any binary file to audio file, has anyone done it previously? I want to listen this noise in Beep form.

So Please help me.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 1):

Any Audio file is a binary one only. There could be different format of audio (like mp3, wav etc), for which the binary content would change. All you need to do save those binary values into a file, and then any audio file player supporting the particular format should able to play it for you.

Comment: I want to convert that into mp3 Format. So that we may listen voice in form of Beep.

Comment: Ok.. the input binary is an audio binary for beep? If so, just save it into a file, then open that with a player, is it playing it as a beep?

Answer (score 0):

I found an old instructables post about some old software written in 2006 to convert files to, in this case, KCS format, which used 22050Hz samplerate, 4 cycles of 1200hz means 0, 8 cycles means 1:

https://www.instructables.com/Storing-files-on-an-audio-cassette/

Unfortunately this doesn't seem to run on 64-bit windows and I've been unable to find any other references to this software. If you are running an older computer or you can probably use an emulator like VMWare/VirtualBox etc it'll probably work.

I also found a newer program (from 2010) written in Python3
http://www.dabeaz.com/py-kcs/ that also uses the KCS format.

Other than that you could look into modem type audio http://www.whence.com/minimodem/